# How to get users by address book

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to develop an iPhone app and implementing a functionality similar to snapchat's and so many other apps. I want to ask for the user's mobile phone number and add it to my database. I then want to ask for permission to access my address book and based on my mobile phone contacts (friends mobile number) I can suggest the profiles of my friends who have installed the app. I developed some functions in which I was able to get all the user's contacts as a string. But I have some issues. People can write the mobile numbers in different ways (putting the country code in first place, etc). Since I am matching an exact string it becomes kind of hard.

Is there any solution for this problem? I know that different countries have different ways of writing the mobile numbers.
F.e. in Portugal we can write 00351 911 111 111 or +351 911 111 111 or 911 111 111 . This will be easy to solve in Portugal since we all have the last 9 digits and it is easy to compare. But in the US I have seen (555) XXX-XXXX or XXX-XXX-XXXX and many other formats.. I can't determine how the user has saved the contact and the same with other countries.

ALL HAPPENS AFTER ASKING FOR AN AUTHORIZATION

In the viewDidLoad I search in Parse the users of my mobile phone

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    var query = PFUser.query()

    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects, error) -> Void in

        if let users = objects {

            self.contactsUsernameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            self.contactsNameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            self.contactsImageFiles.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
            self.contactsNumberArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

            for object in users {

                        for var i = 0; i < self.phoneNumbers.count - 1; i++ {

                            if object["phoneNumber"] as! String == self.phoneNumbers[i] {

                                self.contactsUsernameArray.append(object.username!!)
                                self.contactsNameArray.append(object["name"] as! String)
                                self.contactsNumberArray.append(object["phoneNumber"] as! String)
                                self.contactsImageFiles.append(object["photo"] as! PFFile)

                    }


                }
            }
        }

        //println(self.usernames)
        //println(self.userids)

        self.contactsTable.reloadData()


    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try phone numbers format `E.164`

[E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164)